# Работа со строками в SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

```
SELECT 
 count(z.brak) as brak
,(count ((z.brak)/br.sym_brak)*100) as procent
,n.normativ
,((count(z.brak)/br.sym_brak)*100 )/ n.normativ as otkl
```

Почему-то неправильно считает вот эти две строчки:

```
,(count ((z.brak)/br.sym_brak)*100) as procent
,((count(z.brak)/br.sym_brak)*100 )/ n.normativ as otkl
```

Уже пробовала `sum` вместо `count`, тоже неправильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно в этом:

```
(count ((z.brak)/br.sym_brak)*100) as procent
```

Тут под функцией `Count()` должно быть поле. Ф-я посчитает кол-во записей, удовлетворяющих условию. Для вычисления процента, как я понимаю, надо количество `z.brak` разделить на `br.sym_brak`? Тогда можно попробовать так:

```
count(z.brak)/br.sym_brak*100 as procent
```

А тут

```
((count(z.brak)/br.sym_brak)*100 )/ n.normativ as otkl
```

Тут я не вижу ошибки. Это уже надо смотреть правильность формулы, которую вы используете.

Comment: И ваапстче, не понятен до конца вопрос. Программа считает так, как вы указали ей считать. А так, как вам надо, никому не известно. Напишите, что-ли, как вам надо, чтобы программа считала.

Comment: если так делать:
(count(z.brak)/br.sym_brak)*100 as procent
то процент получаеся  = 0

а вот так правильно считает
(sum(z.brak)/br.sym_brak)*100 as procent

Comment: Такое количество скобок не обязательно. Читать плохо.